# New VM error message on GCP with "resource.sourceMachineImage"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Seeing new error message when changing VM configuration on GCP using the UI:

> Editing VM instance "vm_Instance_1" failed. Error: Invalid
> value for field 'resource.sourceMachineImage': ''. Updating
> 'sourceMachineImage' is not supported.

This started happening last Friday, 4 Mar 2021. What does this mean? How to resolve?

Comment: More details are required. What changes are you making to the VM in the GUI?

Comment: I am just trying to change the current CPU and GPU configuration on the VM. Nothing was working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the is a problem with the UI, but the only workaround for now is using the [gcloud beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/set-machine-type)

```
beta compute instances set-machine-type
```

`gcloud beta compute instances set-machine-type` lets you change the machine type of a virtual machine in the *TERMINATED* state (that is, a virtual machine instance that has been stopped).
For example, if example-instance is a g1-small virtual machine currently in the TERMINATED state, running:

```
gcloud beta compute instances set-machine-type example-instance  --zone us-central1-b --machine-type n1-standard-4
```

#### Edit 1

I've tested on my own project again, and It seems that it is working well now.
You can try again with the UI, it should now be working as before.